# Retrieve Amplify configuration from url with React

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm building a serverless React application and would like to be able to download the aws-exports from a URL before calling Amplify.configure().

At the moment, my App.js contains this:

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
fetch("https://myresource/awsconfig.json")
.then((r) => { Amplify.configure(r) };
```

What would be the best way to do this keeping in mind that all of this needs to happen before loading the rest of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-script. Add a curl command to download the file locally in the start script section of your package.json, then reference the downloaded file in your app.